# After installing git, I cannot get to my version without errors

Tags: git

I just installed git. Entered the required git config user.name, user.email & init.defaultBranch main

**When I enter git status I get :**

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//isicsflsyn01/isicsflsyn01/Django Projects/code''//isicsflsyn01/isicsflsyn01/Django Projects/code' is owned by:
        'S-1-5-21-928949504-4148710699-525549864-3058'
but the current user is:
        'S-1-5-21-1517166318-418398847-1867752156-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///isicsflsyn01/isicsflsyn01/Django Projects/code'
```

**If I enter the suggested:**
`git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///isicsflsyn01/isicsflsyn01/Django Projects/code'`

**I get:**

```
error: wrong number of arguments, should be 2
usage: git config [<options>]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    --local               use repository config file
    --worktree            use per-worktree config file
    -f, --file <file>     use given config file
    --blob <blob-id>      read config from given blob object
```

**Don't know what to do. Please help.**

Comment: Probably the space in the path is giving you trouble. Try escaping it with `\\`.

Comment: @eftshift0: he's on Windows and probably using a shell that requires double quotes instead of single quotes. (Git should recommend double quotes here.)

Comment: `Django Projects/code''/` that’s an oddly named folder … does that complete path exist? Should it? The full path `at '//isicsflsyn01/isicsflsyn01/Django Projects/code''//isicsflsyn01/isicsflsyn01/Django Projects/code'`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is on Windows, to use double quotes, instead of single quotes especially, if you have spacebars in your path. So your command will be:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory "path\to\git\directory"
```

Thanks to [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) for this answer!